# Given the center and radius of a circle, and one axis of an ellipse, find the value of the other axis of the ellipse that lies tangent to the circle.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, conic-sections

[image: Ellipse tangent to circle.]

Find b.

Given the center and radius of a circle, and one axis of an ellipse, find the value of the other axis of the ellipse that lies tangent to the circle.

$$(x - h)^2 + (y - k)^2 = r^2$$

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$$

Also, I feel compelled to add this edit due to the magnificent tedium and confusion I have experienced in attempting to decipher some of the answers:

I have already solved this problem!
I simply mapped the line of all $y$-values for $b$ of the $x$-value of the center of the circle on the offset curve of the ellipse (offset by the radius, of course), then I drew the curve of those values with $b$ on the $x$-axis, and $y$ on the $y$-axis, only to discern the $x$-value of the point of crossing of the horizon extending from the circle's center.

And so, I am not here to have the years eroded away by riddles, nor am I seeking the most lengthy and complicated answer; quite the contrary! I only hope to find the most concise and simple way to solve this particular problem.

There seem to be at least two fairly simple methods:

1. Solving the system of equations
2. The dual-curve crossing

Please dismiss the given numerical values!
I only provided them because I assumed that it would make the problem easier to understand. I was wrong. So, please only use the letter variables, as that turns out to be much less confusing.

I have updated the graphic to include the derivative(s) $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and their perpendiclar(s) $m$.
When I first posted this problem, I thought someone devised a perhaps even simpler solution involving only algebra using the slopes. Do re-post!

Comment: Your thoughts???

Comment: @user101434: Your circle, $C$, can be assumed of center $(0,0)$ and radius $r$ (=$1$ if you want). For each point of $C$ your ellipse can have infinitely many positions and magnitudes for the "other" axis (it can be either the smaller or the larger one).

Comment: The coordinates of the point of tangency will do.
Even only the angle from either the origin of the ellipse or the origin of the circle will suffice.

Comment: It comes down to solving system of two equations. It seems quite nasty one to solve by hand.

Answer (score 0):

We find the coordinates of point of tangency. At this point the derivatives of both functions must be equal:

$(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2\rightarrow y'=\frac{-x+h}{\sqrt{r^2-(x-h)^2}}$

$\frac {x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1 \rightarrow y'=\frac{-bx}{a\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$

This point must also satisfy both equations,

$\begin{cases}\frac{-bx}{a\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}=\frac{-x+h}{\sqrt{r^2-(x-h)^2}}\\y=\frac ba\sqrt{a^2-x^2}=k+\sqrt{r^2-(x-h)^2}\end{cases}$

that is we have following system to solve(for given values):

$\begin{cases}\frac{-bx}{2\sqrt{4-x^2}}=\frac{-x+1}{\sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}}\\y=\frac b2\sqrt{4-x^2}=5+\sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}\end{cases}$

We may write:

$$\frac{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}{1-x}+5=\frac{2\sqrt{4-x^2}}{-bx}+5$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{2x-x^2}+5-5x}{1-x}=\frac{2\sqrt{4-x^2}}{-bx}+5$$

$\Rightarrow$ $$\frac{y-5x}{1-x}+\frac 1{xy}-5=0$$

$$10x^2y+xy^2-5xy+1=0$$

and gives this system to solve:

$$\begin{cases}10x^2y+xy^2-5xy+1=0\\y=5+\sqrt{2x-x^2}\end{cases}$$

which gives $x\approx \frac 12$, $y\approx 4$  and finally gives $b=2\sqrt5\approx 4.47$

[image]

Comment: Yes there are many ways to accomplish this using various computer programs.
However, I am interested in the math.
Could you show how you end up with $x$ alone on one side from:

$$\frac{-x + h}{\sqrt{r^2-(x-h)^2}}=\frac{-bx}{a^2\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}}$$

Comment: As you saw in Wolfarm the analytic solution is complicated and not necessary. Accurate drawing helped me to estimate the value of x and calculate b.However you can reduce this equation and ask it as a another question. may be  a member of this side will give a good analytic answer.

Comment: Are you implying that it is either transcendental or requisite of a hypergeometric series or some other such similar condition? Surely it can't be that difficult, they are two very simple shapes.

Comment: @user101434, I tried to solve the equation. I hope there is no error.

Comment: Your method can lead to the correct solution. You need the point to be on both curves and have parallel tangents, given by what your equation of the slopes leads to after squaring: `(x-2)*(b^2*x^3-4*x^3+12*x-8)=0` in maxima CAS via `solve([x^2/2^2+y^2/b^2-1,(x-1)^2+(y-5)^2-1,b^2*x^3-4*x^3+12*x-8],[b,x,y]);` to 16 complex solutions including the real one we seek: `[b = 4.269419862340216,x = 0.5096816540859862,y = 4.128456735057984]`.

Comment: OKAY.
So the 'system of equations' method looks simple enough.
HOWEVER, I'm pretty confused by the lack of steps shown.
'Sirous', could you show the same equations but with the generic $h$, $k$, $r$, and $a$ variables?
I seem to have confused myself with my choice example.

Comment: @user101434, I included equations with  generic h, k. r and a.

Answer (score 0):

> Given $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2=1,$ find the values of $b>0$ that gives an ellipse tangent to $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2.$

```
R=QQ[x,y,a,b,h,k,r,MonomialOrder=>Eliminate 2]
I=ideal((h*x+k*y+1)^2-r^2*(x^2+y^2),-a^2*x^2-b^2*y^2+1,determinant matrix{{diff(x,(h*x+k*y+1)^2-r^2*(x^2+y^2)),diff(x,-a^2*x^2-b^2*y^2+1)},{diff(y,(h*x+k*y+1)^2-r^2*(x^2+y^2)),diff(y,-a^2*x^2-b^2*y^2+1)}})
```

$$(a^4r^2-2a^2h^2r^2+h^4r^2-2a^2r^4-2h^2r^4+r^6)b^8+(-2a^6r^2+6a^4h^2r^2-6a^2h^4r^2+2h^6r^2-4a^4k^2r^2+6a^2h^2k^2r^2-2h^4k^2r^2+2a^4r^4+4a^2h^2r^4-6h^4r^4+6a^2k^2r^4+4h^2k^2r^4+2a^2r^6+6h^2r^6-2k^2r^6-2r^8)b^6+(a^8r^2-4a^6h^2r^2+6a^4h^4r^2-4a^2h^6r^2+h^8r^2+6a^6k^2r^2-10a^4h^2k^2r^2+2a^2h^4k^2r^2+2h^6k^2r^2+6a^4k^4r^2-6a^2h^2k^4r^2+h^4k^4r^2+2a^6r^4-8a^4h^2r^4+10a^2h^4r^4-4h^6r^4-8a^4k^2r^4-6a^2h^2k^2r^4-6h^4k^2r^4-6a^2k^4r^4-2h^2k^4r^4-6a^4r^6-8a^2h^2r^6+6h^4r^6+4a^2k^2r^6+6h^2k^2r^6+k^4r^6+2a^2r^8-4h^2r^8-2k^2r^8+r^{10})b^4+(-2a^8k^2r^2+6a^6h^2k^2r^2-6a^4h^4k^2r^2+2a^2h^6k^2r^2-6a^6k^4r^2+2a^4h^2k^4r^2+4a^2h^4k^4r^2-4a^4k^6r^2+2a^2h^2k^6r^2-2a^8r^4+6a^6h^2r^4-6a^4h^4r^4+2a^2h^6r^4+4a^6k^2r^4-6a^4h^2k^2r^4+2a^2h^4k^2r^4+10a^4k^4r^4+2a^2h^2k^4r^4+2a^2k^6r^4+2a^6r^6+4a^4h^2r^6-6a^2h^4r^6-8a^4k^2r^6-10a^2h^2k^2r^6-6a^2k^4r^6+2a^4r^8+6a^2h^2r^8+6a^2k^2r^8-2a^2r^{10})b^2+a^8k^4r^2-2a^6h^2k^4r^2+a^4h^4k^4r^2+2a^6k^6r^2+2a^4h^2k^6r^2+a^4k^8r^2-2a^8k^2r^4+4a^6h^2k^2r^4-2a^4h^4k^2r^4-6a^6k^4r^4-6a^4h^2k^4r^4-4a^4k^6r^4+a^8r^6-2a^6h^2r^6+a^4h^4r^6+6a^6k^2r^6+6a^4h^2k^2r^6+6a^4k^4r^6-2a^6r^8-2a^4h^2r^8-4a^4k^2r^8+a^4r^{10}$$

Then solve this quartic in $b^2.$

**Older answers**

> Given $x^2/2^2+y^2/b^2=1,$ find the values of $b>0$ that gives an ellipse tangent to $(x-1)^2+(y-5)^2=1.$

Since $x=2$ is an outer common tangent for all $b$ there's a unique solution.

We can find the tact invariant as in [3264 conics in a second](http://www.ub.edu/sga/201819seminari/Timme-slides.pdf) in [M2](https://www.unimelb-macaulay2.cloud.edu.au/#home) with $c=\frac1{b}:$

```
R=QQ[x,y,c,MonomialOrder=>Eliminate 2]
I=ideal(x^2/2^2+c^2*y^2-1,(x-1)^2+(y-5)^2-1,determinant matrix{{diff(x,x^2/2^2+c^2*y^2-1),diff(x,(x-1)^2+(y-5)^2-1)},{diff(y,x^2/2^2+c^2*y^2-1),diff(y,(x-1)^2+(y-5)^2-1)}})
gens gb I -- matrix {{19008*c^8-2187*c^6+81*c^4-c^2, 65*y-7489152*c^6+760302*c^4-18138*c^2-325, 13*x-1406592*c^6+98478*c^4-816*c^2-26}}
```

$19008c^8-2187c^6+81c^4-c^2=0.$

$c \approx 0.2342238546756076$

$b \approx 1/0.2342238546756076\approx 4.269419958889189$

Note $c=0, b=\infty$ i.e. the line pair $x^2=2^2$ comes out as a solution, but is not an ellipse.

This method also solves the more general

> Given $x^2/2^2+y^2/b^2=1,$ find the values of $b>0$ that gives an ellipse tangent to $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2:$

$(16h^4k^4+32h^2k^6+16k^8-32h^4k^2r^2-96h^2k^4r^2-64k^6r^2+16h^4r^4+96h^2k^2r^4+96k^4r^4-32h^2r^6-64k^2r^6+16r^8-128h^2k^4+128k^6+256h^2k^2r^2-384k^4r^2-128h^2r^4+384k^2r^4-128r^6+256k^4-512k^2r^2+256r^4)c^8+(8h^6k^2+16h^4k^4+8h^2k^6+8h^6r^2+8h^4k^2r^2+8h^2k^4r^2+8k^6r^2-24h^4r^4-40h^2k^2r^4-24k^4r^4+24h^2r^6+24k^2r^6-8r^8-96h^4k^2+32h^2k^4-64k^6-96h^4r^2-96h^2k^2r^2+160k^4r^2+64h^2r^4-128k^2r^4+32r^6+384h^2k^2-384k^4+384h^2r^2+256k^2r^2+128r^4-512k^2-512r^2)c^6+(h^8+2h^6k^2+h^4k^4-4h^6r^2-6h^4k^2r^2-2h^2k^4r^2+6h^4r^4+6h^2k^2r^4+k^4r^4-4h^2r^6-2k^2r^6+r^8-16h^6+8h^4k^2-24h^2k^4+40h^4r^2-24h^2k^2r^2-24k^4r^2-32h^2r^4+16k^2r^4+8r^6+96h^4-160h^2k^2+96k^4-128h^2r^2-128k^2r^2-96r^4-256h^2+384k^2+128r^2+256)c^4+(2h^6-2h^4k^2-6h^4r^2+4h^2k^2r^2+6h^2r^4-2k^2r^4-2r^6-24h^4+24h^2k^2+16h^2r^2+24k^2r^2+8r^4+96h^2-64k^2+32r^2-128)c^2+h^4-2h^2r^2+r^4-8h^2-8r^2+16=0$

Then solve this quartic in $c^2=(\frac1{b})^2$ for given $h,k,r.$

**Old first attempt**

The dual curves are $4X^2+b^2Y^2=1$ and $10XY+24Y^2+2X+10Y+1=0.$ The common tangents are given by $x(P_i)x+y(P_i)y+1=0,$ where $P_i$ are the intersection points of the duals. When $b\approx 4.26941996$ the inner common tangents coincide, as we can see using a slider in geogebra.

[image: ctb]

**Old secoond attempt**

It may seem we reduced to the same type of situation, finding when the dual curves are tangent. But, now $b$ does not appear in a fraction.

So, now we can find the tact invariant as in [3264 conics in a second](http://www.ub.edu/sga/201819seminari/Timme-slides.pdf) in [M2](https://www.unimelb-macaulay2.cloud.edu.au/#home)

```
R=QQ[x,y,b,MonomialOrder=>Eliminate 2]
I=ideal(10*x*y+24*y^2+2*x+10*y+1,-4*x^2-b^2*y^2+1,determinant matrix{{diff(x,10*x*y+24*y^2+2*x+10*y+1),diff(x,-4*x^2-b^2*y^2+1)},{diff(y,10*x*y+24*y^2+2*x+10*y+1),diff(y,-4*x^2-b^2*y^2+1)}}) -- b^6-81*b^4+2187*b^2-19008
```

giving a cubic in $b^2.$ The roots in maxima CAS:

```
allroots(b^6-81*b^4+2187*b^2-19008);
  [b = 4.269419958889195,b = -4.269419958889191,
   b = 0.6731641510895302*%i-5.642621428168951,
   b = (-0.6731641510895302*%i)-5.642621428168951,
   b = 0.6731641510895462*%i+5.642621428168949,
   b = 5.642621428168949-0.6731641510895462*%i]
```

Comment: The internet is surprisingly sparse when it comes to dual curves. I couldn't find a single decent video to help translate Wikipedia's article. However, from your method, I seem to have discerned:

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

dual curve is:

$$a^2x^2+b^2y^2=1$$

But I can't figure out the other... which is:

$$(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2$$

dual curve is:

$$? ? ?$$

Please and thanks.

Comment: @user101434: $(x-1)^2+(y-5)^2=0$ has dual the double line $(X+5Y+1)^2=0.$

 $(x-1)^2+(y-5)^2=1$ has dual $(X+5Y+1)^2-(X^2+Y^2)=0,$ which is a hyperbola. But seriously, it's given by the conic with the inverse matrix of the matrix of the circle as a conic.

Comment: I see...what about  $(x-g)^2+(y-k)^2=w^2$ ?
What might be the dual curve of that?

Comment: @user101434: $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2$ has dual $(hX+kY+1)^2-r^2(X^2+Y^2)=0.$

Comment: @user101434: The general solution is in the update.